# How to subscribe redis channel from nuxt app

Tags: vue.js, redis, publish-subscribe, nuxt.js

I have a nuxtjs frontend app and a php backend running on a different server.
I'm setting up a real time chat. The backend publish to a redis server once a new message has been sent (i.e "hey I received a new message for room "foo", get it and go get notify other recipients"). So I'm supposed to subscribe a specific redis channel and then notify others.
My thinking is more about the way I should approach this.
Do I need something like socket.io to talk to my redis server ?
Should I use only redis.createClient() to initiate a redis instance and then subscribe (dynamically) to each and every new room I can already be in or added ?

[image]

Comment: Ever figure out how to do this?